# Match numbers with

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am having the following list of numbers which I would like to match:

```
44Th/s
40ksol/s
76Th/s
40Th/s
485Mh/s
432Mh/s
7Th/s
365Mh/s
33Th/s
3.1Th/s
6Th/s
1.1Gh/s
2.4Th/s
1.155Th/s
112.155Gh/s
```

I am using `=regexreplace(A2,"[^\d]","")` to match the numbers part. However, when a number looks like that `1.155Th/s` I get back `1155`.

[image]

I also tried the following regex `\d*[.]\d*`, which only gives me back:

```
 3.1
 1.1
 24
1.155
112.155
```

Any suggestions how to also get the numbers part that looks like that `1.155, 112.155 or 3.1`?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Your regex currently says to remove any characters that aren't 0-9 digits so it's working exactly as it should

Comment: @faris I would also like to get the numbers that are separated by a point.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a great source for testing out regex patterns to see where your issues are

Comment: Adding a `.` to get `=regexreplace(A2,"[^\d.]","")` doesn't work?

Comment: Do you want to use `REGEXREPLACE` by all means? You may also use `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "^(\d+\.)|\D+", "$1")` (even `"(\d+\.)|\D+"` will work here, too), but I think the extracting function is the more natural choice here unless we do not know more background of the issue you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest *extracting* the float/int value using [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en#):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A24, "\d+(?:\.\d+)?")
```

This will extract the first occurrence of a substring that starts with 1+ digits and is followed with an optional sequence of `.` and then 1+ digits.

[image]

Comment: Multiply the result by 1 to get number instead of text.